# Salesforce PostInstallation code

Tags: apex, isv

In my PostInstallation code I need to access the Salesforce organization id, organization name. In salesforce documentation I read that it is a special user which has all the permissions to run this code. Can I get my required information from this special user? Or is there any other way I can get the required information in the Post installation code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an [InstallHandler](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_install_handler.htm) that on completion sends an email with this subject line:

```
private void sendSuccessEmail(InstallContext context) {
    User user = [Select Name, Email from User where Id = :context.installerId()];
    String subject = 'Xyz InstallHandler executed in org '
          + UserInfo.getOrganizationName() + ' '
          + UserInfo.getOrganizationId()
          + ' for user "' + user.Name
          + (context.previousVersion() != null
                  ? ' (previous version was ' + context.previousVersion() + ')'
                  : '');
```

So the organization id and organization name are available through the normal `UserInfo` object in this context.

Comment: Thank you @keith for the reply. can we also get the Userinfo.getUserName() from the InitialContext. I am guessing 'NO', could you please confirm? Thank you and appreciate your reply and time!!

Comment: @Tara The InstallContext documentation isn't easy to find but there is some here [How does a Post Install Script Work?](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=apex_post_install_script_intro.htm&language=en). So the idea is to query or use UserInfo for additional information.

Comment: Thank you Keith!! Yes, Userinfo.getUserEmail is not available for the Installcontext object. As per the following link - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm